# android fragment vs spinner onitemselected listener

Tags: android, spinner, adapter

i have a fragment with spinner in which i add data from internet

in onCreateView() i init my spinner and add listener for it

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, null);

        cityChoose = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.cityChoose);
        cityChoose.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {            
                    HashMap temp = new HashMap();
                    temp.put("finset", cities.get(position).getValue());
                    HashMap map = new HashMap();
                    map.put("city", temp);
                    new DownloadData().execute(new Object[] { PARAM_DEALS_LIST,
                            map, getStoreID(), "1", "15" });
                }
            }
```

Then in on onCreate i first add data to spinner

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (Tools.isNetworkAvailable(getActivity().getApplicationContext())) {
            new DownloadData().execute(new Object[] { PARAM_BOTH, "",
                    getStoreID(), "1", "15" });
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                    getResources().getString(R.string.toastNoInternet),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Then if user go from this fragment to another fragment and click back button from it i need to show in spinner my data that i was add early i do this in such way

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        if (spinAdapter != null) {
            cityChoose.setAdapter(spinAdapter);
        }
    }
```

And my problem is this:

If i first go to the fragment, spinner will download data and filled with it by adapter, then if i go to another fragment and then push back button the spinner will get data from adapter, all works good, but if i in fragment with spinner click on one of its items and then go to another fragment and went back it will init its onItemSelected() method and download data one more time, but the adapter already has this data.
How i can avoid initing onItemSelected() in spinner when i back to this fragment from another ?